# Why won't python write to this open file?

Tags: python

I'm tinkering with python (fairly inexperienced with the language) and file i/o, and ran across the following error:

`ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Pretty straightforward, so I dropped in a print statement to check the state of `outfile`, to see what was going on with my code:

```
import json

data = {'thing1' : 'foo', 'thing2' : 'bar'}

def writeToJSON():
    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        print outfile.closed    # outputs 'False', as expected
        jsonifiedData = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':'), ensure_ascii=False)
        outfile.write(unicode(jsonifiedData))    # trace identifies this line as the issue

writeToJSON()
```

Indentation seems clean, so what's going on here?

The file appears open at runtime, but the interpreter immediately complains about writing to said file after conveying as much.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Added the entire file.

Also, this is the complete output when running `blurp.py`:

```
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "blurp.py", line 11, in <module>
  writeToJSON()
File "blurp.py", line 9, in writeToJSON
  outfile.write(unicode(jsonifiedData))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: Can you show the traceback error?

Comment: Checked this on my Linux, and it seems everything is OK.

Comment: @wanderlust, hm... I'm on macOS, python 2.7.13, perhaps it's a system thing... I'll try this on my linux machine too.

Comment: @Dinesh.hmn I'll drop in the error message momentarily.

Comment: Show the trace.  Show the *exact* code.  As is the code won't do anything.  Make a reproducible example.

Comment: Could this potentially be a spaces/tabs issue where the `outfile.write` isn't indented the way it appears to be?

Comment: @rlee827 **great catch!** Sublime wasn't showing that level of whitespace granularity, and summarized four spaces as a tab. Highlighting the whitespace revealed the distinction. Thank you very much!

Comment: @rlee827 would you like to post the answer, or would you rather I do the typing? I'm cool with either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rlee827 astutely and correctly proposed the possibility of a whitespacing issue. The whitespace leading up to the offending characters, consisted of two tabs and four spaces, something that was not visible in my editor. Replacing the four spaces with a single tab fixed the issue.

Thanks to everyone who chimed in to help, and an extra thanks to @rlee827 for resolving this!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the issue on your side, but I tried the same piece of code (python 3.5) and it's working.

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {'thing1' : 'foo', 'thing2' : 'bar'}
>>> def writeToJSON():
        with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
            print (outfile.closed)
            jsonifiedData = json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':'), ensure_ascii=False)
            outfile.write(str(jsonifiedData))
>>> writeToJSON()
False
>>>
```

and content of data.json is

```
{
    "thing1":"foo",
    "thing2":"bar"
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you trying this out for me.
Looks like @rlee827 was on the right track with the whitespacing issue.